Classification of Second Order PDEs Depends on the Coefficients of the Mixed Partials?
I'm reading through Evans' texbook on PDEs, and am struggling with the definition for classifying second order equations. For $n\geq 2$, he classifies a second order semilinear PDE with principle part
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(x)u_{x_i,x_j}
$$
as elliptic at a point p if the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}(p)$ (the matrix defined component-wise as $A_{ij}(p)=a^{ij}(p)$) are all the same sign, parabolic if $\boldsymbol{A}$ has any zero eigenvalues, hyperbolic if the eigenvalues all have the same sign except one, and super hyperbolic otherwise.
As an example, consider a second order PDE with principle part
$$
u_{xx} + 4u_{xy} + 3u_{yy}
$$
This implies that
$$
\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4\\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has the positive eigenvalues $1,3$, so the equation should be classified as elliptic. However, if we assume continuous second order partial derivatives (which seems like a standard assumption in Evans), then $u_{xy} = u_{yx}$, so we could just as well write the principle part as
$$
u_{xx} + 2u_{xy} + 2u_{yx} + 3u_{yy}
$$
which gives
$$
\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has the eigenvalues $2\pm \sqrt{5}$, which have opposite sign. Another valid principle part is
$$
\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
3 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has the eigenvalues $4, 0$, which would suggest the equation is really parabolic. This seems to suggest that this definition doesn't really apply when $n=2$, and instead the definition based on the determinant $d=ac - b^2$ should be used. But, in principle, this definition should "say the same thing": since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$, if $d=0$, then there is a zero eigenvalue, if $d>0$, then all eigenvalues have the same sign, etc. except in this definition, we (seemingly arbitrarily) write the principle part as
$$
a(x,y)u_{xx} + 2b(x,y)u_{xy} + c(x,y)u_{yy}
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
a(x,y) & b(x,y)\\
b(x,y) & c(x,y)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Maybe $\boldsymbol{A}$ is just implicitly assumed to be symmetric in Evans. Any help understanding this apparent discrepancy in the definitions is greatly appreciated.

It's assumed to be symmetric or is made symmetric by instead using $\tilde{A} = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$, which results in the same PDE for $u\in C^2$. Notice that none of the conditions consider complex eigenvalues, which can't occur for real symmetric matrices.

Thanks! Another thing I noticed was that, the change of variables to transfer the equation to standard form depends on how you write $\boldsymbol{A}$, for example, under an arbitrary change of coordinates $\boldsymbol{f}$
$$
\boldsymbol{A}'=[\boldsymbol{J}\boldsymbol{f}]\boldsymbol{A}[\boldsymbol{J}\boldsymbol{f}]^\top
$$
where $\boldsymbol{A}'$ are the coefficients of the second order partials following the coordinate transformation. The correct choice of $\boldsymbol{f}$ is then
$$
[\boldsymbol{J}\boldsymbol{f}]= \boldsymbol{D}\boldsymbol{X}^\top
$$

where
$$
D_{ii} = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert\lambda_i\rvert}}& \lambda_i\neq 0\
0 & \lambda_i=0
\end{cases}
$$
and $X$ is the matrix whose column vectors are the normalized eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol{A}$. Clearly, if $\boldsymbol{A}$ is symmetric, then its guaranteed to be diagonalizable, but if its not symmetric (and is still diagonalizable), this gives an appropriate change of coordinates, right? Or do we still have to assume $\boldsymbol{A}$ is symmetric in this case?

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is not symmetric, then the eigenvectors aren't guaranteed to be orthogonal, and $\boldsymbol{X}^\top\neq\boldsymbol{X}^{-1}$, so the above transformation actually does not transform the equation into standard form.

You just make $A$ symmetric using the transform I gave above. This can always be done if you assume solutions are smooth
